# How to cut a paper recursively?

Tags: java, recursion

I am doing an assignment on recursion and I am really stuck in this question..

A4 paper. The width-to-height ratio of paper in the ISO format is the square root of 2 to 1. Format A0 has an area of 1 square meter. Format A1 is A0 cut with a vertical line into two equal halves, A2 is A1 cut with a horizontal line into two halves, and so on. Write a program that takes an integer command-line argument n and uses StdDraw to show how to cut a sheet of A0 paper into 2^n pieces.

StdDraw is just a library to draw something in the canvas specifically made for the course. In this case we can use StdDraw to draw a line to represent cutting a paper.

Comment: Which part are you stack with? As you said, StdDraw is something made for your course so we have no idea how to use that.

Comment: I am confused about what to use for my base case.   
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/A_size_illustration.png
This is the format in which we have to cut the paper and StdDraw just helps me to draw a line which represents cutting a paper. If we have a width and height of say 1000 by 1000 we have to cut it into 2^n pieces. so we have to reduce the x coordinate and y coordinate repeatedly so what can i use for my base case?

Comment: Ask a person who gave you the assignment. How are we supposed to know which size are you supposed to use as a base. I'd assume A0 but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and the link that you provided I think 2<sup>n</sup> should be replaced with 2n and if that is the case then the following recursive static method produces your desired result:

```
public static void papercut(int n, double size, double x, double y)
{
    if (n == 0) return;
    double x2 = x + size, y2 = y + 2*size;
    StdDraw.line(x, y, x, y+4*size);
    StdDraw.line(x-2*size, y, x+2*size, y);
    papercut(n-1, size/2, x2, y2);  
}
```

You could test it with:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    papercut(n, 0.25, 0.5, 0);
}
```

and see that it exactly produces a figure like the one you provided in your link (but the first cut in the link is horizontal while your question asks that the first cut should be vertical).

Answer (score 0):

When the paper is in Portrait Orientation, the following works;

```
import java.awt.Color;


public class PaperCut {

// draw a rectangle with the given coordinates and color
    public static void drawRectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height, Color color) {
    StdDraw.setPenColor(color);
    StdDraw.rectangle(x, y, width / 2, height / 2);
}

// recursively cut a rectangle into four smaller rectangles
    public static void cutRectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height, int n) {
        if (n == 0) return; // base case
    // draw the current rectangle
        drawRectangle(x, y, width, height, StdDraw.BLUE);

        StdDraw.show();
        StdDraw.pause(1000);
    // cut the rectangle along the longer side
        if (width >= height) {
        // cut into left and right halves
            cutRectangle(x - width / 4, y, width / 2, height, n - 1); // left half
            cutRectangle(x + width / 4, y, width / 2, height, n - 1); // right half
    } else {
        // cut into top and bottom halves
            cutRectangle(x, y + height / 4, width, height / 2, n - 1); // top half
            cutRectangle(x, y - height / 4, width, height / 2, n - 1); // bottom half
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // get the command-line argument
        double width = 1; // width of A0 paper
        double height = Math.sqrt(2); // height of A0 paper
    
        StdDraw.setScale(-width / 2, width / 2); // set the scale of the canvas
        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering(); // enable double buffering for smooth animation
        cutRectangle(0, 0, width/2, height/2, i);
        
}
}
```